# Saving the val return from ionic-datepicker into Firebase

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, ionic-framework, firebase

I am using ionic-datepicker ([ionic -datepicker](https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker)) to let user pick a time. I have this code in my controller to return the val user picked:

```
$scope.datePickerCallback = function (val) {
        if(typeof(val)==='undefined'){      
            console.log('Date not selected');
        }else{
            console.log('Selected date is : ', val);
            $scope.pickedDate = val;
        }
    };
```

Then I try to $add the task object (contain this val in one of its property like task.date) into an $firebaseArray. My firebase keep return a permission denied:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /tasks/-JwIkrTLg5XvrhjLVRTJ failed: permission_denied
```

I console log it before add into firebase. The output of the date property is:

date:  Fri Aug 21 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT) 
The **proto**: Invalid Date.

So how to save a date object into Firebase? Do I need to set some rules for that? Or do I need to do something with the val to save it. One thing I need to do is to have the val like Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP. So I can convert the date value into different readable time format, do time calculation and all sort of stuffs. I can convert the val to String and save successfully in Firebase. But I will lost all the functionality a date object can do (like with moment.js with the return value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase can only store valid JSON types and a JavaScript `Date` is not such a type.

There are two common reasons you want to store a date/time:

1. to display it later
2. to compare it to other date/times

If your reason for storing the date is that you want to display it later, you'll want to store it as a string:

```
task.date = val.toString();
```

If you want to store the date so that you can later compare it to other dates (or get all tasks in a time period), you'll want to store the so-called timestamp of the date:

```
task.timestamp = val.getTime();
```

The [`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) function of JavaScript returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

If you use different properties for both types, you can store both a textual display value and a numeric value that you use for sorting. Alternative you can reconstruct the `Date` from the timestamp with:

```
new Date(task.timestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks Frank! So is it val.getTime() will turn val into a unix timestamp number same as Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP?